# How to integrate cut() into predict() in predicting a variable for a model I created

Tags: r, stat

**R-Programming:** Using the ISLR library, I want to predict someone's wage if they are age 35, with a supposed model that utilizes the function cut() with values 0, 35, 45, 55, 65, 80 to cut variable "age" into different brackets. With that being said, how should the predict() code look like with cut() and my model in consideration?

Here is my code so far prior to predict():

```
table(cut(age, breaks = c(0, 35, 45, 55, 65, 80))) # cut()

getfit.1 = lm(wage~education+cut(age, breaks = c(0,25,35,45,55,80)),data=Wage) # model with cut()
```

Answer (score 2):

You will make your life easier if you create the categorical variable and then use it to fit the model:

```
library(ISLR)
agecat <- cut(Wage$age, breaks = c(0,25,35,45,55,80))
getfit.1 <-  lm(wage~education+agecat,data=Wage)
predict(getfit.1, data.frame(education="2. HS Grad", agecat="(25,35]"))
#        1 
# 88.56445
```

Note, you must specify the education category as well to get a prediction. As a result it may be useful to get all the the combinations:

```
cross <- expand.grid(agecat=levels(agecat), education=levels(Wage$education))
predictions <- data.frame(cross, pwage=predict(getfit.1, cross))
head(predictions)
#    agecat    education    pwage
# 1  (0,25] 1. < HS Grad 59.12711
# 2 (25,35] 1. < HS Grad 77.65516
# 3 (35,45] 1. < HS Grad 91.86200
# 4 (45,55] 1. < HS Grad 90.84853
# 5 (55,80] 1. < HS Grad 88.53072
# 6  (0,25]   2. HS Grad 70.03640
```